# Infinite loop while reading stdio.h

Tags: c++

why does the following program gets stuck in an infinite loop??

```
int main()
{
    string fname = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\include\\stdio.h";
    char line[985];

    ifstream file(fname.c_str());

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"unable to open";
        exit(0);
    }

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file.getline(line,'\n');
        cout<<line<<'\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: stdio.h has nothing to do with this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to getline() is stream size and third is the delimiter.

Instead of this:

```
file.getline(line,'\n');
```

Try with this:

```
file.getline(line,256,'\n');
```

Comment: well I tried that but it didn't work. And also the length of the longest line was 282 characters so I tried to set the size of 'line' to more than 3 times the required length but still it didn't work..

Comment: You don't need to worry about the length of the longest line. `getline()` reads either `size` specified or until it hits delimiter. I ran your code on Linux with the path to stdio.h. It prints correctly.